# How does K-Means work when initial centroid locations far away from the data are selected?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

From my understanding of K-means clustering, k is chosen, centroid locations are selected, samples are assigned, and then the centroid moves to the mean of the samples, until there is no more movement.

[image]

So in this example, if 3 centroids are chosen with locations of (5,1), (5,10), and (5,20), what happens? I would expect all the samples to be assigned to the (5,1) centroid which would then move to the mean of the data (5,0) and the algorithm would terminate with all of the samples belonging to 1 cluster (the other centroids not moving, and with 1 iteration).

However, when I implement this in Python, using `KMeans`, it doesn't behave like this:

```py
In [3]: xa = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   ...: xb = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
   ...: 
   ...: data = pd.DataFrame({"Xa": xa, "Xb":xb}, columns=["Xa", "Xb"])
   ...: 
   ...: initial = np.array([[5,1], [5,10], [5,20]])
   ...: 
   ...: km = KMeans(n_clusters=3,init=initial, n_init=1, max_iter=1).fit(data)
   ...: print(km.cluster_centers_)
[[ 4.5  0. ]
 [10.   0. ]
 [ 9.   0. ]]
```

Letting the algorithm run with no limit on the number of iterations results in the following, which also doesn't make sense to me:

```py
In [4]: km = KMeans(n_clusters=3,init=initial, n_init=1).fit(data)
   ...: print(km.cluster_centers_)
[[3.  0. ]
 [9.5 0. ]
 [7.  0. ]]
```

Could anyone explain my misunderstanding here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

The overall goal of k-means is to subdivide data into k clusters in such way, that the sum of distances between data points and centroids of their assigned clusters is the smallest possible. There is no guarantee that the iterative k-means algorithm will produce clusters minimizing this sum, but its implementations should reject clearly bad solutions. Returning some empty clusters is obviously not optimal, since in such a situation we can do better by subdividing a non-empty cluster into a few smaller ones.

For this reason, implementations of the k-means algorithm use various methods to avoid empty clusters. The implementation used by `sklearn` checks at each iteration step if empty clusters were produced. If this is the case, then the code selects data points that are furthest away from their cluster centers, and relocates the centers corresponding to the empty clusters to these furthest points. The functions in the `sklearn` source code that perform this step are [_relocate_empty_clusters_dense](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/cluster/_k_means_common.pyx#L159) and [_relocate_empty_clusters_sparse](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/cluster/_k_means_common.pyx#L200).